# How to style buttons in Firemonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin

Are there special steps for styling a button using stylebook in FMX? because whenever I change my style it works in the viewer only, however when I run the program nothing changes although stylebook setting are properly connected to style files and to the application as well, also if I close the program and start it again I find the same style saved and exists in the view but when run the application I cant find any style, can anyone tell me the exact steps? because I check tutorials, docs, help but still stylebook wont apply the new changes to the app at run time. Thanks.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7msG.png)

Comment: You did `Form.stylebook := stylebook1;` ?

Comment: Which Delphi version? There has been some changes over time.

Comment: yes, my stylebook connected properly to my form. (Delphi 10.1)

Comment: Also what is the `Style` you choose and for which platform?

Comment: For exemple : If you choose `GoogleGlass.fsf` and run your app on Win platform that will not work.

Comment: Did you apply the style on the appropriate device view?

Comment: Platform is windows, style is Air.style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To modify the default style**:

1. Start with a blank `fmx` form and add a `TButton`.
2. Right-Click on the button and select `Edit Default Style ...` - the Style Designer opens
3. In the *Structure pane* select Buttonstyle - text
4. In the *Object Inspector* change the `NormalColor` property to `Crimson`. The text of the button changes to `Crimson` (red) color.
5. Hit the designer view `Close` button (X) and confirm to `Apply changes ...` by clicling `Yes` when prompted. Note that a `Stylebook` has been added to the form.
6. Build and run

The result looks like this on Windows 7

[image]

Maybe you have omitted step 5 (just guessing)

**With an existing stylebook and style do as follows**:

1. Start with a blank `fmx` form and add a `TButton`.
2. Add a `TStyleBook`, set its `UseStyleManager` property, double-click it and load an existing style (e.g. Air)
3. In the structure pane select `buttonstyle` - `text`. Note that available properties are not necessarily the same as when editing the default style.
4. In the *Object Inspector* change the `Font` - `FontColor` property to `Yellow`. The text of the button changes to yellow color.
5. Hit the designer view `Close` button (X) and confirm to `Apply changes ...` by clicling `Yes` when prompted.
6. Build and run

The result looks like this on Windows 7

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly if I don't have a stylebook, But if I got a stylebook changes wont applied! (take a look to the new image attached)

Comment: @Evie I added directions how to modify the existing styles.

Comment: Thanks very much it's working, your step number 2 did the trick, My mistake was assigning the style file through FileName property which did not work for me, but after double click the stylebook as you have mentioned and load the style file from there.. now it is working perfectly.